# what is the best way to find the closest @client.event.starts_at vs Time.now?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

**What is the best way to fetch latest event in the past and soonest event in the future?**

Client.rb:

```
has_many :events
```

Event.rb:

```
belongs_to :client
validates :starts_at, presence: :true
```

Clients_controller.rb:

```
@soonest_event = @client.events.where("starts_at >= ?", Time.zone.now).order("starts_at ASC").first.starts_at
@latest_event = @client.events.where("starts_at <= ?", Time.zone.now).order("starts_at DESC").first.starts_at
```

Client/show:

```
Soonest event in the future:
= distance_of_time_in_words(Time.now, @soonest_event)  
Latest event in the past:
= distance_of_time_in_words(Time.now, @latest_event)
```

If a client does not have a past event or a future event, it **shows an error** in the controller like:

```
undefined method `starts_at' for nil:NilClass
```

1) How can I make the code more efficient?

2) How can I tackle the error?

Comment: you need to sort by ASC in the first query, but other than that, what do you mean, it "does not work"?

Comment: You can hide these two queries in a stored procedure. Will be faster to run and look nicer in the app code.

Comment: Or not even a stored procedure. Just send these two queries as one with `UNION` (faster). And extract query building/execution to a QueryObject (nicer).

Comment: It does not work because `limit(1)` returns an `ActiveRecord_Relation` not an `Event`. Change `.limit(1)` to `.first.starts_at` to return a time (needed as a second argument of `distance_of_time_in_words`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it with:

Client.rb:

```
  def next_event
    events.where("starts_at >= ?", Time.zone.now).order("starts_at ASC").pluck(:starts_at).first
  end
  def last_event
    events.where("starts_at <= ?", Time.zone.now).order("starts_at DESC").pluck(:starts_at).first
  end
```

Client/show:

```
    - if @client.last_event.present?
      = distance_of_time_in_words(Time.now, @client.last_event)
    - if @client.next_event.present?
      = distance_of_time_in_words(Time.now, @client.next_event)
```